How to fix cyclical dependency in EF Core 8
I am stuck in this problem for so many days and started to realize that using EF Core was a mistake because I am not able to find out the solution to this basic problem and also planning to switch to Dapper for easy data access solution.
However, I thought to ask this question here to find any remedy from expert.
I have FileSystemRuleApp and CatalogRuleApp deriving from RuleApp class, FileSystemRuleApp is not listed as it is not relevant here, but only CatalogRuleApp should persist into the database. Also I am using temporal tables to store the history of RuleApp to maintain the versioning.
Here are the definitions of my domain models:
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public abstract class DefinitionBase : BusinessEntity
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    
    //[DataMember]
    //public virtual DefinitionBase Parent { get; set; }
}

public interface IRevisionState
{
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    public List<EndPoint> EndPoints { get; set; }
    public List<DataElement> DataElements { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public abstract class RuleApp : DefinitionBase, IRevisionState
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    public List<EndPoint> EndPoints { get; set; }
    public List<DataElement> DataElements { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public sealed class CatalogRuleApp : RuleApp, IIdentifiableEntity
{
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Revision { get; set; } = 1;

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string RevisionState
    {
        get
        {
            var serializer = (DataContractSerializer<RuleApp>)AppWide.Container.Resolve<IXmlSerializer>();
            var xml = serializer.SerializeToXml(this);
            return xml;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                return;

            var serializer = (DataContractSerializer<RuleApp>)AppWide.Container.Resolve<IXmlSerializer>();
            var revision = serializer.DeserializeFromXml<IRevisionState>(value);

            if (revision != null)
            {
                Categories = revision.Categories;
                Entities = revision.Entities;
                EndPoints = revision.EndPoints;
                DataElements = revision.DataElements;
            }
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public CheckIn CheckedIn { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public CheckOut CheckedOut { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class CheckIn : BusinessEntity, IIdentifiableEntity
{
    #region Navigation
    public CatalogRuleApp? RuleApp { get; set; }
    public Guid RuleAppId { get; set; }
    #endregion

    [DataMember]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string? Comments { get; set; }

    #region IIdentifiableEntity members
    public Guid EntityId
    {
        get => Id;
        set => Id = value;
    }
    #endregion
}

Here is the EF Core configurations, where CheckOut class has the same definition as CheckIn:
class RuleAppEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<RuleApp>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<RuleApp> builder)
    {
        builder.HasNoDiscriminator();

        builder
            .Ignore(x => x.Categories)
            .Ignore(x => x.DataElements)
            .Ignore(x => x.EndPoints)
            .Ignore(x => x.Entities); // Error Throws here

        builder.ToTable(nameof(RuleApp), b => b.IsTemporal());
    }
}

class CatalogRuleAppEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CatalogRuleApp>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CatalogRuleApp> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(RuleApp))
            .Ignore(x => x.EntityId)
            .HasNoDiscriminator();

        builder.Property(e => e.RevisionState).HasColumnName("State");

        builder.Property(p => p.Version).IsRowVersion();
    }
}

class CheckInEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CheckIn>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CheckIn> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable($"{nameof(CheckIn)}s", b => b.IsTemporal())
            .Ignore(x => x.EntityId);
    }
}

class CheckOutEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CheckOut>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CheckOut> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable($"{nameof(CheckOut)}s", b => b.IsTemporal())
            .Ignore(x => x.EntityId);
    }
}

The problem starts, when adding a Parent property to DefinitionBase:
[DataMember]
public virtual DefinitionBase Parent { get; set; }

I'm getting this error:

The property 'Categories' cannot be ignored on type 'RuleApp' because it's declared on the base type 'DefinitionBase'. To exclude this property from your model, use the [NotMapped] attribute or 'Ignore' on the base type in 'OnModelCreating'.
Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

The goal of adding Parent in the base class is to have an ability to define parent for any derived class.
While I don't want to save DefinitionBase explicitly in the database, how to mitigate this issue?
Note: I am using .NET 8 with latest EF Core v8.0.8

All of your problems here are because you're misusing EF entity types as DTOs: you should not be using EF entities as DTOs: remove those [Serializable] and [DataContract] attributes and define DTOs as separate types.
`

I am intentionally using it to avoid having multiple types, mappings and their management. However, does removing it solves the problem?

"I am intentionally using it to avoid having multiple types, mappings and their management" - reading this really makes my blood-pressure go up... this is not how you're meant to do OOP. By your logic you don't need a separate toilet and computer chair: just move your toilet to your desk because that avoids having multiple seats, furnishings and their maintenance, no?

I respect your wide knowledge. I may not be using it wisely but you should understand that I may be lacking understanding of how normally this situation is handled. To best of my knowledge this is not OOP concept I am violating. If you help me understand in the logical way, I may understand my mistake here.

@Dai, can you share any article to help me understand my flaw in my design?

API contract should not have influence on Database Model. It is my principe. Also loading whole object for just serilization several fields is not right way.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv, after some further reading, I understand why it is important to separate the DTOs from Entities. Dai also tried to elaborate the same point which was not evident to me earlier.
